# Change background image using key-frames, background image is white after switching to other app and go back to browser

Tags: css, iphone, css-animations

I'm using key frames to change the background image of a div, so far so good, the images change as I expect.

However, on iOS devices, when I switch to other app and go back to browser, the background images disappeared.

iOS version: 14+

Tested on iPhone 7, 8, 11.

Browser tested: Chrome, Safari.

This does not happen on Android.

You can check this fiddle and test for yourself.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Okay so it seems I can't put the fiddle link inside so here it is https://jsfiddle.net/74e6qazx/

Comment: Background-image is not an [animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties), do you have to put background-image inside a keyframe?

Comment: It's not that I have to use keyframes, but I can use it to achieve the current behavior in fiddle (previous image fades out slowly and the next image fades in slowly on top of it)

Comment: Well, if so you can try to separate each image in a different `div` then use keyframes to control the opacity of each `div`. It's better to use opacity than something that's not animatable like background-image.

Comment: That totally makes sense. Will try.

Comment: @phucbm Can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section, I'd put them here as an answer.

Since `background-image` is not an [animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties), it is not recommended to put `background-image` in a keyframe. Instead, try to separate each image in a different `div` then use keyframes to control the `opacity` of each of them.

Opacity is one of the [properties that have good cross-browser support](https://web.dev/animations-guide/#browser-compatibility).